# Azure policy to auto add user group in resource group contributors

Tags: azure

This is my first project in Azure. Please avoid if any mistake. I have a user group "Azure Cross Team Contributors". I want to add it in resource group contributors by default whenever I create any resource group. I got to know there is policy, But not able to write policy rule. What would be policy rule for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Similar thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/55249/index.html) answered on Microsoft Q&A , so updating here for broader community usage. Thank you [AshishMishra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/ashishmishra-0875/) and [DCtheGeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/dcthegeek/) for helping on the thread.

Azure Policy lets you audit the compliance of the configuration of Azure Resource Manager (ARM) properties.

In some cases, such as AKS or Guest Configuration, it can also audit configuration of Resource Provider properties. While Azure Policy can be used to audit how a role definition is defined ([sample here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/General/CustomSubscription_OwnerRole_Audit.json)), it isn't for applying roles to specific objects. That's the domain of [Azure role-based access control (RBAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview).

If you want the group "Azure Cross Team Contributors" to have access to all resource groups within a subscription, an easier alternative is to grant the role assignment at the [subscription scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview#scope).

There isn't a built-in role with the name "Resource Group Contributors".

Feel free to revert back if you have any further queries. Thank you.